# select value with space jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
</form>

<p>Click the button to change the selected fruit to banana.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "banana";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_value) setting value of `select option` on button click. When button is clicked the value will be `banana` when i change the value of banana with `banana 1` it is not showing anymore.How to make it in a way that it will still accept the value even if there is a space

Comment: it is working for me. Have you change banana 1 for option value also?

Comment: in the tutorial in the link i change `document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "banana";` to document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "banana 1"; then when i click the button `try it` it is not showing anymore

Comment: After you done the changes first click on "See result" then on "Try it"

Comment: @MLM put the explanation in my answer , check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also if you are checking for banana 1 there should be a value called banana 1 so it gets the value . Otherwise it will just give a blank dropdown as it cant find that value.

For checking for banana 1 you will have to change the function's checking value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#make_ora").click(function () {

    $("#mySelect").val("banana 1");

    });


  });
</script>
</head><body>

Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect" class ="mys">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="banana 1">Banana 1</option>
</select>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<input type='button' value='Change to banana 1' id='make_ora'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `$("#mySelect").val("dasdas adsad");` it is not showing this is why i mean. because what if i dont have the checking value i want to change the text how can i do it?

Comment: @MLM it wont show anything as there is no value like that in the dropdown

Comment: @MLM you are trying to replace javascript with jquery?

Comment: i am working on it in jquery and i just follow that sample but in my project in jquery i noticed that if value has space it is not shown i change the value on click and the way i change the value is `$("#idofselect").val(datafromdatabase)`

Comment: @MLM edited it to JQuery , it works :) hope i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting value of Selection tag will reflect only if any one of options value matches with set value.  If you want to set value as "banana 1" it should have Banana.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:-

```
var c=document.getElementById("mySelect");
c.value="banana 1";
alert(c.value);/* Only For Check*/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
<option value="banana 1">Banana 1</option>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "banana 1";
}
</script>
```

First do above change in your w3schools editor

Then click on "See Result"

Then click on "Try it"

It should work

Answer (score -1):

```
 <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>

From among the option values there is no "banana1" in the select option value.so thats why it is not appearing .
instead of  choose other option values like---orange (or)pineapple..
its working.
```